# np.fromstring to check string contains only integers and separator

Tags: python, numpy

As illustrated in the following example, passing `4y` to `numpy.fromstring` with separator `x` does not result in an error.

```
#Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  1 2019, 02:16:23) 
#[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
#Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.fromstring("4y", sep="x")
array([4.])
```

Is it possible somehow to have it raise an error if the given string does not contain *only integers and separators* ?

I can come up with a solution using a regular expression, but is it possible to do it more easily ?

EDIT :

**Objective**
The actual goal here is to parse command line option retrieved with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

1. User passes a command `python3 my_program.py --my_arg 4x4`
2. With `argparse` library, `option.my_arg` is equal to `"4x4"` (it's a string)
3. `np.fromstring` is used to split `"4x4"` to `[4, 4]` which should be an array of integers.

So if the given argument is not correctly formatted, for example if an unexpected letter is inserted (`"4c4"` instead of `"4x4"`), I want the program to raise an error.

Comment: `assert set(mystring) - set('0123456789x') == set()`

Comment: I think you cannot make this with np.fromstring() as it simply tries to parse the string as it can and ignoring the rest. better write a check function using regex, filters or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Do you know any alternate method similar to `np.fromstring()` but which doesn't ignore some string elements ? I mean which raises an error if encountering a wrong value.

Comment: I mean you can cleanse the data before passing it through to `numpy`... but it really depends what you are trying to do here.  Ignore anything that's not numeric nor the seperator? Stop completely if an unexpected element is found?

Comment: @r.rook the latter. I use this method to parse input data. I was surprised to see that passing incoherent data didn't give me any error. I understand it may sound like nitpicking, but I just wanted to really understand this matter.

Comment: `input data` - as in `input()` or read from a file?  How many values do you expect?  For just one, `int(input())` works; or a list `[int(x) for x in input().split(sep)]`.  Or try `np.array(your_string.split(sep), dtype=int)`.  All of these will throw an error if a substring (after split) is not a valid integer format.

Comment: @hpauli `input data` as in command line parameter passed to my program with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.
You understood my point, and your solution is quite nice. I will edit my post so my goal is more clear for future readers